# AWS Beanstalk read full path to folder with nlp model

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am looking for best practices and recommendations for reading a folder path with my C# Web API hosted in AWS Elastic Beanstalk. When running my code locally I reference the model using:

```
string modelPath = "C:/Data/nlp/models/";
```

What is the best way to accomplish this with in Elastic Beanstalk? What is the best approach to store large model files and reference within the code deployed to Beanstalk? I do not want to add them to the Web API bin, they are 500x the size of the API itself.

Comment: Put it on s3 and pull from s3 as part of building the vm

Comment: Thank you @SamH. I understand that I can deploy from S3 within Beanstalk, but where do the models actually get stored once the environment is built? What would that path look like? Also, wouldn't this still push the large model files every time I push an update? I am hoping to store them somewhere else so they are not part of every deploy.

Comment: Beanstalk works by redeploying on update. If your model doesn’t change that much, maybe you want to store it in EBS, and attach that EBS (elastic block storage, I think is what EBS stands for. I imagine it like a hard drive that they plug into the VM) every time you redeploy

Comment: Where do models get stored / what’s the path? ANS: you would put the file somewhere, that would be its path. Wouldn’t this pull the model every deploy? Yes, but your code gets put in s3 and pulled every deploy, so doesn’t seem like a big concern. S3 to ec2 transfer is fast. But you should look at EFS as well https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/services-efs.html